# Change the text color of notification to Google Chat to Red in Kibana

Tags: logging, kibana

I have a watcher in Kibana through which I am generating error logs. The watcher will send a notification to Google Chat. But I want to change the color of the text of the Notification to Red. That is, if the notification is generated, it should be visible in red color in Google Chat. How can I do that ? Below is the watcher json:

```
  {
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "indices": [
          "Logs-*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "kubernetes.container.name": "Name1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "sev": "Error"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "msg": "*Some Random Text*"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "2022-01-01T00:00:00",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gt": "0"
      }
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "namespace": "ABC"
},
  "actions": {
    "GoogleChatNotification": {
      "webhook": {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "chat.googleapis.com",
        "port": 443,
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "path",
        "params": {
          "key": "Key",
          "token": "Token"
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "Sample Text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I please get help on the above ? Thanks in advance.